# Prevent scrolling on element with "overflow: hidden"?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

`overflow: hidden` prevents users from scrolling with input devices, but it's still possible to scroll the element with `focus()`, `scrollIntoView()`, etc. I have some content that should be hidden with `overflow: hidden`, but calling `focus()` on a hidden input sometimes causes the browser to scroll the `overflow: hidden` element and reveal the hidden content.

Here's a demo where the right element should always be hidden:

```js
document.querySelector('input').focus();
// document.querySelector('.right').scrollIntoView(); works too
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 200vw;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  width: 100vw;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.right {
  width: 100vw;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">
    right
    <input />
  </div>
</div>
```

Adding `position: fixed` to `.right` fixes this issue, but it introduces other styling issues. Is it possible to make `body` never scrollable without using `position: fixed`?

The issue I'm facing is caused by React calling `focus()` when a hidden input has the `autoFocus` property. It's called in [ReactDOMHostConfig's commitMount](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/d9e0485c84b45055ba86629dc20870faca9b5973/packages/react-dom-bindings/src/client/ReactDOMHostConfig.js#L503). Even if I add a lint rule to disable React's `autoFocus`, it's likely that someone will call `focus()` and cause a bug.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is `overflow: clip;` instead of `overflow: hidden;`.

`clip` will hide content that is not within immediate view and will not allow for any kind of programmatic scrolling including user tabbing.

> Overflow content outside the clipped region is not visible, user agents do not add a scroll bar, and programmatic scrolling is also not supported... The element box is not a scroll container.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#clip

Comment: Didn't know that one, nice.
This will be the valid answer in a few months/years, but sadly [only 89% support](https://caniuse.com/?search=overflow%3Aclip) for now (2023-07), so bear in mind that the value won't be well supported on many browsers.

Comment: doesn't work in Chrome for me. it's still scrolling even with overflow: clip

Answer (score 1):

**With javascript**

```js
document.querySelector('input').focus();
document.querySelector('.right').scrollIntoView();

document.querySelector('.left').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  document.querySelector('input').focus();
  document.querySelector('.right').scrollIntoView();
    console.log('focus input');
});

// Reset the scroll from javascript
window.onscroll = function() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  console.log('reset scroll');
};
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 200vw;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  width: 100vw;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.right {
  width: 100vw;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">left - click me</div>
  <div class="right">
    right
    <input />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I ended up doing the same blasphemy

Answer (score 0):

You set overflow: hidden on both the html and body elements so that the body will not be scrollable. Then, you set overflow: scroll on the .right element, so that if focus() is called on a hidden input, the .right element will scroll instead of the body.

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 200vw;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.right {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```